# ¿Como poder imprimir bien la cadena de texto?

Tags: c

> Elabore un programa en lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c) para el siguiente enunciado:
>
> > El programa debe solicitar un número entero que contemple hasta 3 dígitos (unidades, decenas y/o centenas), para luego presentar ese número escrito en palabras. Por ejemplo: si enviamos 57 el resultado debe ser CINCUENTA Y SIETE. Defina por lo menos 3 funciones donde cada una representa a las unidades, decenas y centenas, en cada función debe existir un arreglo con las palabras. También deberá utilizar una función que retorne las palabras finales que equivalen al número introducido y presentarlo en el main.

Entonces este es mi codigo y al momento de imprimir no me sale correctamente como tendría que salir.

<sub>Se que todavía me faltan varias cosas</sub>

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *unidad(int f1);
char *decena(int f2);
char *centena(int f3);

main(){

  int numero,u, d, c;
  char j[6];
  char k[7];
  char l[10];


printf("\n\nBIENVENIDO INGRESE UN NUMERO (1 AL 999)\n\n");
  printf("INTRODUZCA EL NUMERO: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

  u=numero%10;
    numero=numero/10;
    d=numero%10;
    numero=numero/10;
   c=numero%10;

   if(c!=0 && d!= 0){
        printf("LA CENTENA ES: %d\n\n",c);
         printf("LA DECENA ES: %d\n\n", d);
        printf("LA UNIDAD ES: %d\n", u);
    }

 else{
 if(d!= 0){
  printf("LA DECENA ES: %d\n\n", d);
  printf("LA UNIDAD ES: %d\n\n", u);
 }


    else{
        printf("LA UNIDAD ES: %d\n\n", u);
    }
 }



strcpy(j, unidad(u));
  strcpy(k, decena(d));
  strcpy(l, centena(c));

   printf(" el numero en palabras es: %s %s %s",l, k, j);
   getch();




}//MAIN



char *unidad(int f1){
 char arreglo1[9][6]={"UNO","DOS","TRES", "CUATRO","CINCO","SEIS","SIETE","OCHO","NUEVE"};
  return(arreglo1[f1-1]);
 }

char *decena(int f2){
    char arreglo2[7][8]={"DIEZ","DIECI","ONCE","DOCE", "TRECE", "CATORCE","QUINCE"};

  char arreglo3[16][30]={"VEINTE","VEINTI ","TREINTA", "TREINTA Y ", "CUARENTA","CUARENTA Y ","CINCUENTA","CINCUENTA Y","SESENTA","SESENTA Y ","SETENTA","SETENTA Y","OCHENTA","OCHENTA Y","NOVENTA","NOVENTA Y"};

  return(arreglo2[f2-1]);





}
char *centena(int f3){
    char arreglo4[10][20]={"CIEN","CIENTO","DOSCIENTOS","TRECIENTOS","CUATROCIENTOS","QUINIENTOS","SEISCIENTO","SETECIENTOS","OCHOCIENTOS","NOVECIENTOS",};
   return(arreglo4[f3-1]);

 }
```

Comment: Hola Guillermo. Puedes explicar en mas detalle por qué no sale `"correctamente como tendria que salir"?`. Un saludo

Comment: hola que tal, bueno el programa tiene que convertir de numeros a letras y mi problema es al momento de imprimir la palabras del numero introducido, porque no tengo mucho conocimiento en las funciones y si me imprime palabras pero no del numero correcto por  **ejem. intorduzco 123 y me imprime cien once tres**

Comment: Eso ya lo vemos... pero ya que has leído el apartado "_cómo preguntar_" deberías saber que tienes que especificar qué es lo que no te funciona... tu código tiene unos cuantos errores y corregirlos todos así de primeras se sale un poco del ámbito de StackOverflow

Comment: a okay disculpa  **eferion**

Comment: Por si lo ha parecido, no te estoy regañando... solo te estoy explicando cómo funciona SO. Si quieres que la gente te responda tienes que enfocar la pregunta lo máximo posible... encontrarse con una situación en la que para responder tienes que copiarte un programa entero y ponerte a depurarlo a ver qué encuentras no es demasiado alentador

Comment: Por cierto, para enviarle un mensaje a alguien en particular pon una arroba antes del nombre. Así le aparecerá una notificación

Comment: @eferion muchas gracias por los conejos creeme que ire mejorando mis preguntas y bueno si tienes razon con respecto al programa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero, te dicen que tienes que tienes que convertir un número en su representación escrita, es decir:

- 1 -> uno
- 102 -> ciento dos

Por lo que la salida del programa debe ser algo tal que:

```
printf("%s%s%s",cadena_centenas,cadena_decenas,cadena_unidades);
```

Para conseguir esta secuencia tenemos que prestar atención a las particularidades de las decenas y las centenas:

- números del 11 al 15 tienen una nomenclatura aparte.
- las decenas enteras se escriben diferente a las decenas con unidades:

  ```
  20 -> veinte
  21 -> veintiuno
  30 -> treinta
  31 -> treinta y uno
  ```
- Las centenas se escriben diferente si no poseen ni unidades ni decenas:

  ```
  100 -> cien
  101 -> ciento uno
  ```

Con esto en mente la función de las unidades es trivial:

```
char *unidad(int unidades){
 char *arreglo[]={"","UNO","DOS","TRES", "CUATRO","CINCO","SEIS","SIETE","OCHO","NUEVE"};
 return arreglo[unidades];
}
```

La explicación es sencilla: a cada posición le corresponde su traducción directa... la posición 0 está vacía porque el cero no tiene traducción pero es un dígito a tener en cuenta.

Las decenas se complican un poco ya que, como hemos visto, pueden depender de las unidades:

```
char *decena(int decenas, int unidades){
  char *arreglo1[]={"","DIEZ","VEINTE","TREINTA","CUARENTA", "CINCUENTA", "SESENTA", "SETENTA", "OCHENTA", "NOVENTA"};
  char *arreglo2[]={"","DIECI","VEINTI","TREINTA Y ","CUARENTA Y ", "CINCUENTA Y ", "SESENTA Y ", "SETENTA Y ", "OCHENTA Y ", "NOVENTA Y "};

  if( unidades == 0 )
    return arreglo1[decenas];
  else
    return arreglo2[decenas];
}
```

La explicación sigue siendo sencilla: Si las unidades son 0 entonces se devuelve un elemento del primer arreglo; en el resto de los casos se devuelve un elemento del segundo arreglo. Nuevamente reservamos un espacio en el arreglo por si las unidades valen 0 (cadena vacía)

Y con las centenas pasa exactamente lo mismo que con las unidades:

```
char *centena(int centenas, int decenas, int unidades){
  char *arreglo1[]={"","CIEN","DOSCIENTOS","TRESCIENTOS","CUATROCIENTOS","QUINIENTOS","SEISCIENTOS","SETECIENTOS","OCHOCIENTOS","NOVECIENTOS"};
  char *arreglo2[]={"","CIENTO ","DOSCIENTOS ","TRESCIENTOS ","CUATROCIENTOS ","QUINIENTOS ","SEISCIENTOS ","SETECIENTOS ","OCHOCIENTOS ","NOVECIENTOS "};

  if( decenas == 0 && unidades == 0)
    return arreglo1[centenas];
  else
    return arreglo2[centenas];
}
```

Y ya esta... no, espera. Faltan los números que van por libre (rango 11-15). Estos números tienen como particularidad que agrupan unidad y decena así que les dedicamos una función propia:

```
char *especiales(int decenas, int unidades)
{
  char *arreglo[6] = {"","ONCE","DOCE","TRECE","CATORCE","QUINCE"};

  int valor = decenas*10+unidades;

  if( valor >= 11 && valor <= 15 )
    return arreglo[valor-10];
  else
    return arreglo[0];
}
```

Es facil de explicar... si el número está en el rango 11-15, devolvemos su correspondiente traducción directa y en caso contrario devolvemos una cadena vacía.

¿Cómo se agrupa todo esto? Con un main la mar de sencillo:

```
main(){

  printf("\n\nBIENVENIDO INGRESE UN NUMERO (1 AL 999)\n\n");
  while(true)
  {
    printf("INTRODUZCA EL NUMERO: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    int u=numero%10;
    numero=numero/10;
    int d=numero%10;
    numero=numero/10;
    int c=numero%10;

    char* cadena_centena  = centena(c,d,u);
    char* cadena_decena   = decena(d,u);
    char* cadena_unidad   = unidad(u);
    char* cadena_especial = especiales(d,u);

    if( *cadena_especial )
    {
      printf("%s%s\n",cadena_centena,cadena_especial);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%s%s%s\n",cadena_centena,cadena_decena,cadena_unidad);
    }
  }
}
```

Como no es mi intención dartelo todo hecho (si te da por copiar el ejercicio tal cual piensa que te podrán preguntar por qué lo has hecho de esta manera y no de otra), la tarea de entender esta parte del código corre de tu cuenta.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS AMIGO @eferion me ha quedado claro eran esas las dudas que tenia con respecto a la decena y disculpa la molestia y tranquilo con tu explicacion lo comprendi claro, muchas gracias por guiarme y los consejos y saludos...

Answer (score 1):

Esta respuesta no es para solucionarte el ejercicio, sin embargo te explico por que te pasa esto.
El problema es en `decena`:

```
char *decena(int f2){
  char arreglo2[7][8]={"DIEZ","DIECI","ONCE","DOCE", "TRECE", "CATORCE","QUINCE"};

  char arreglo3[16][30]={"VEINTE","VEINTI ","TREINTA", "TREINTA Y ", "CUARENTA","CUARENTA Y ","CINCUENTA","CINCUENTA Y","SESENTA","SESENTA Y ","SETENTA","SETENTA Y","OCHENTA","OCHENTA Y","NOVENTA","NOVENTA Y"};

  return(arreglo2[f2-1]);
}
```

Como puedes ver en el return siempre devuelves `arreglo2[f2-1]`. Este es el arreglo en caso que la decena sea 1, adoptaria esa forma en dependecia de la unidad. Tambien necesitas usar `arreglo3` que es el que te da este valor.
Por ejemplo si llamas a `decena(2)` entonces `arreglo2[1] = "DIECI"`, cuando el resultado esperado seria "VEINTE" o "VEINTI" en dependencia de las unidades.
Te puedes auxiliar de estos links para que veas otros ejemplos de este ejercicio
http://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Dev-C/1371057-Ayuda-con-codigo-Dar-un-numero-en-letras.html
https://saforas.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/codigo-c-convierte-numero-a-letras/

Comment: oh gracias, es exacto hay es donde en realidad me da el problema al momento de imprimir la decena no se como hacer pero probare tu sugerencia, muchas gracias. @Theia

Comment: @GuillermoNavarro Te puse 2 links que te pueden ayudar con tu problema, a pesar de que estan en c++, pero bueno, el lenguaje es bastante parecido ;)

Comment: muchas gracias @Theia ya solucionare mi problema

Comment: @GuillermoNavarro Gracias por el feedback. Es bueno saber que fui de ayuda. Podrias votar en mi respuesta como util ya te ayudo a solucionar tu problema?